# Wrong timestamp inserted when I call the update method on controller from another laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm calling an update method from a laravel app unfortunately a wrong updated_at is inserted with one hour delta despite the timezone is the same on each sides
You can see the difference here between the result of a dump of the source datetime and the query on the other side, there is a difference of one hour :
[image]

Here is the code I use in order to call the remote controller:

```
$updatedIntranet = new DateTime($stagesIntranet[$key]->updated_at);
                $stageSiteValueIndex = array_keys($stagesSiteIds,$id);
                
                echo('id : '. $id);
                $updatedsite = new DateTime($stagesSite[$stageSiteValueIndex[0]]->updated_at);
                $diffTimestamps = $updatedIntranet->getTimestamp() - $updatedsite->getTimestamp();

                echo '------- updated intranet ---------<br />';
                dump($stageIntranet->updated_at);
               
                echo '-------- updated site --------<br />';
                dump($stagesSite[$stageSiteValueIndex[0]]->updated_at);
               
                echo '--------diff--------<br />';
                
                
                // site must be updated
                if( $diffTimestamps != 0)
                {
                    dump('delta : '.$diffTimestamps);

                    $countUpdated++;

                    $stageIntranet->id = $stageIntranet->id_stages;
                    unset($stageIntranet->id_stages);
                   
                    
                    $stageIntranetCleanUTF8 =  $this->utf8ize($stageIntranet->toArray());
                    
                  
                    $stageIntranetJson = json_encode($stageIntranetCleanUTF8,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
                    
                    
                    $updateResponse = $client->put(
                        $this->updateTarget.'/'.$stageIntranet->id,
                        [
                            'json'=>[$stageIntranetJson],
                        ]
                    );
    
                    dd($updateResponse->getBody()->getContents());
                    
                }
```

So next time I launch the code delta should be 0 and unfortunately there is always 3600 seconds as you can see

[image: next launch]

Comment: please use dot in sentences !!!

Comment: What are the timezone settings for both apps in config/app.php?

Comment: 'timezone' => 'Europe/Paris'

Comment: probably daylight saving time

Comment: How do you change this ? Is it a server parameter ? tzdata are ok on remote

Comment: tzdata are ok on both sides.

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, it's a breaking change since Laravel 7 you must override the default Datetime serialization in your model, see : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#date-serialization